# How to enable PDF search option using embed or Iframe in HTML

Tags: html, pdf, iframe, embed

How to enable PDF search option in all browsers using Embed or Iframe. It should work in mobile browsers too.

Comment: [Try to Solve The Problem First](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)   --   
[How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)   --   [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)    --    [I Downvoted Because](https://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/)

Answer (score 0):

The PDF search feature is variable from "Browser" to "Browser-extensions" and platform to platform, thus there is NO one search works for all.

The search PDF fragment was introduced by Adobe for their Acrobat PDF Viewer browsing extension. Thus in theory should work with all Acrobat plug-ins, however your milage can vary per browser version etc.

FireFox PDF.js should respond to a search query but Current Edge generally does not. So Chrome based browsers with or without Acrobat (current majority) may not work but Mozilla / Firefox varieties generally will.
[image]

As an  example test your browser with this search

https://africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf#search=demonstration

Correct Result
[image]

Note:- it is **not case sensitive**
https://africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf#search=more
[image]

Order of words is not maintained and a bigger issue for URL compatability the "many word spaces" should be double quoted  thus requires %encoding  `%22continued%20demonstration%20page%22`
https://africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf#search=%22continued%20demonstration%20page%22
[image]

One strength is you can combine with others such as `#page=2&search=....`
https://africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf#page=2&search=%22continued%20demonstration%20page%22
[image]

So current Chrome Acrobat plugin needs manual search
[image]