# Navigate to a specific text of a pdf using its coordinates

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, pdf-generation, jspdf, pdf.js

I have a pdf uploaded in a html dom.
I have the pdf and the coordinates (x,y) of a text/line/paragraph from the pdf.
I want to navigate to the exact location of that text/line in the pdf using the coordinates as input parameters and highlight the area enclosed by the coordinates.

Is it acheivable using pdf.js ?

Answer (score 1):

Generally those methods within browsers are highly variable based on system and version so take for example attempting to scroll to the `zzzzz` line
this works in Chromium/Edge:-
https://africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf#page=1&view=fitH&zoom=0,0,225

[image]

For Firefox PDF.js to get to a similar place you need
https://africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf#page=1&zoom=FitH,625

[image]

For a word search Firefox works but modern chrome or chrome with acrobat appears not to work also see https://stackoverflow.com/a/73299830/10802527

Comment: thanks for the comment..
if I have coordinates (x,y) axis of the area covered for a line/ paragraph.
Can we navigate to that location or highlight that location ?